# Interop adding an image to a Paragraph using C#

Tags: c#, interop

I'm writing a word document using C# and now in need to add an image in the current paragraph.

The current line adds to the TOP of the document

```
aDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path);
```

but my need is to add the image on a selected paragraph, so something like:

```
Paragraph parag = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
parag >> InlineShapes.AddPicture(path, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

How can I find the way to add in on the Paragraph itself?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking to add it to the `Range` of the paragraph.

```
parag.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: In my opinion, nothing in Word Interop is intuitive :)

Comment: Any thought on how to SIZE the actual image to something i can control from C# ?

Comment: `AddPicture()` returns an `InlineShape` that has a height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,there is method for inserting image to specefic position.

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
var docRange = document.Range();
docRange.Start = 3;//your expected index of the whole doc

Word.InlineShape i_shape = 
question_para.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(question.Q_image.url,ref 
missing,ref missing,docRange);
```